# map 2D list with corresponding position in the list

Tags: python, arrays

I have following 2D-Array like:

```
[['4470', '4753.5', '5682', '4440', '6113.5', '3661.5', '7555.3', '6090.3', '5147.3', '4296'], ['4468.5', '4742.5', '5297', '5501.8', '5061.3', '2933.5', '6367.5', '6053.8', '5654.3', '3793.3']]
```

I want to transform it to a new list with each element mapped to its position in the overall list like:

```
[[('1','4470'),('2', '4753.5'), ...], [('11', '4468.5'), ...]]
```

Position in next sub-list should be the next value from the previous sub-list. Also, the length of each sub-list is same.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, your question is not clear. Are you saying you want to replace each string in that 2D array with a 2-tuple that includes the original string and an increasing integer in string format? Does that increasing integer key reset for each list in the overall list, or does it increase over the entire list?

Comment: Obviously it is clear how u can see it xD

Comment: Please, dont make any Hatespeeches. It shows that u want makeyourself very important

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify that that second sublist should be starting with 1 or will continue with the number from the previous sub-list

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem with your code.

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Moinuddin It should started with the number of previous sub list for continue

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this, you may use [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with *nested list comprehension* expression as:

```
my_list = [['4470', '4753.5', '5682', '4440', '6113.5', '3661.5', '7555.3', '6090.3', '5147.3', '4296'], ['4468.5', '4742.5', '5297', '5501.8', '5061.3', '2933.5', '6367.5', '6053.8', '5654.3', '3793.3']]
sub_list_len = len(my_list[0])  # all the sub-lists are of constant length

new_list = [[(str(i), j) for i, j in enumerate(sub_list, n*sub_list_len+1)] \
                 for n, sub_list in enumerate(my_list)]
```

Final value hold by `new_list` will be:

```
[[('1', '4470'), ('2', '4753.5'), ('3', '5682'), ('4', '4440'), ('5', '6113.5'), ('6', '3661.5'), ('7', '7555.3'), ('8', '6090.3'), ('9', '5147.3'), ('10', '4296')], [('11', '4468.5'), ('12', '4742.5'), ('13', '5297'), ('14', '5501.8'), ('15', '5061.3'), ('16', '2933.5'), ('17', '6367.5'), ('18', '6053.8'), ('19', '5654.3'), ('20', '3793.3')]]
```

Comment: Good answer-- that's certainly one way to do it. Unfortunately I think it would be unusual for a beginner to pull off a one-liner like that.

Comment: Oh thx, but it should started with 11 on the second list and not with 1 again. Can u help me?

Comment: @Okalj Are all the sub-lists of the same length?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Yes, it is

Comment: U are the best, homie

Comment: No need to say thanks. You should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you, and you think it is worth accepting. Also, I have made an edit to your question. Please take a look at it and be clear on asking the question from next time. You will get better response from the community :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def list2tupple(array):
    return_list = []
    for item in array:
        for iteration, value in enumerate(item):
            return_list.append((str((iteration+1)), str(value)))
    return return_list
```

**Exapmle**:

```
a = [['a']]
print(list_tupple(a))
output: [('1', 'a')]
```

You could use list comprehension for this, but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to give you an example as simple as it gets, I created a new list, and counter to know which key I'm on.

I iterate my_list through each sub-list, than I iterate through each sub-list item.

Than I'm creating a tuple which I'll append to a new list.

```
    my_list = [['4470', '4753.5', '5682', '4440', '6113.5', '3661.5', '7555.3', '6090.3', '5147.3', '4296'],
           ['4468.5', '4742.5', '5297', '5501.8', '5061.3', '2933.5', '6367.5', '6053.8', '5654.3', '3793.3']]

new_list = []
count = 1  # the key
for sub_list in my_list:  # gets both of the sub lists
    for item in sub_list:  # gets the items in each list
        new_list.append((str(count), item))  # appends a tuple to a new list
        count += 1
```

Since your question included the words: key and value I will add another way to arrange my_list to key and value inform of [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
my_list = [['4470', '4753.5', '5682', '4440', '6113.5', '3661.5', '7555.3', '6090.3', '5147.3', '4296'],
           ['4468.5', '4742.5', '5297', '5501.8', '5061.3', '2933.5', '6367.5', '6053.8', '5654.3', '3793.3']]

new_dict = {}  # new dictionary
count = 1  # the key
for sub_list in my_list:  # gets both of the sub lists
    for item in sub_list:  # gets the items in each list
        new_dict[count] = item  # appends key and value to the dict
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing but different - using [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

```
import itertools

a = [['4470', '4753.5', '5682',  .....]]

item_nbrs = itertools.count(1)
def tuples(iterable):
    for thing in iterable:
        yield (next(item_nbrs), thing)

z = [list(tuples(iterable)) for iterable in a]
```

---

A bit more functional:

```
item_nbrs = itertools.count(1)
f = map(tuples, a)
g = map(list, f)
h = list(g)
```

or

```
item_nbrs = itertools.count(1)
k = list(map(list, map(tuples, a)))


>>> z == h == k
True
>>>
```